# How to fix SVG animate which does not work in Safari

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Not later than yesterday, I managed to make an animated SVG which works flawlessly in Chrome. I tried to open it in Safari today and the animation was not working. Is there a solution to this? I have tried to do some research but most of them show CSS3 and the `d:path` CSS method does not work either and is actually worse because nothing shows up.

Here's my code

```html
<svg width="1279" height="650" viewBox="0 0 1279 650" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M-138 -167.889C-138 -167.889 2002 -494.389 1020.73 -167.889C39.4558 158.611 1111.22 305.526 942.746 516.955C681.205 845.177 -138 458.649 -138 458.649V -167.889Z" 
    fill="#000000">
    
    <!-- First shape and last shape in values are the same -->
    <animate 
            repeatCount="indefinite" 
            fill="#454599" 
            attributeName="d" 
            dur="12s" 
            values="
                M-138 -167.889C-138 -167.889 1986.46 -591.778 1020.73 -167.889C55 256 1148.99 306.909 942.746 516.954C736.5 727 -138 458.649 -138 458.649V-167.889Z;

                M-138 -167.889C-138 -167.889 1923.96 -760.278 1020.73 -167.889C117.5 424.5 1248.99 269.909 942.746 516.954C636.5 764 -138 458.649 -138 458.649V-167.889Z;

                M-138 -167.889C-138 -167.889 1989.46 -765.777 1020.73 -167.889C52 430 1302.99 226.348 942.746 516.955C582.5 807.561 -138 458.649 -138 458.649V-167.889Z;

                M-138 -167.889C-138 -167.889 1986.46 -591.778 1020.73 -167.889C55 256 1148.99 306.909 942.746 516.954C736.5 727 -138 458.649 -138 458.649V-167.889Z;
            ">
        </animate>
    </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Remove leading and trailing white spaces from your `values` attribute, Safari is picky... https://jsfiddle.net/yhq7xgvp/

Comment: Does it make a difference if you define explicit `keyTimes`?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks! Removing trailing whitespaces fixed it lol.

Comment: @ccprog I'm not too sure about the keyTimes as I didn't try them. Removing whitespace fixed it. I will try the keyTimes and see if those work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have tried to do some research but most of them show CSS3 and the
> d:path CSS method does not work either and is actually worse because
> nothing shows up.

Please see [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=path%20css)  `d: path` animations.
Unfortunately, this does not work in the specified browsers, including Safari.
Let's hope to see better support in the near future.

This answer will not solve your problem with CSS3 path animations as it is not possible, but it will make it easier with SVG animations that work in all modern browsers, including Safari.

[**Specifying path data: the `d` property:**](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#paths-TheDProperty)

> For animation, two d property values can only be interpolated smoothly
> when the path data strings contain have the same structure, (i.e.
> exactly the same number and types of path data commands which are in
> the same order). If an animation is specified and the lists of path
> data commands do not have the same structure, then the values must be
> interpolated using the discrete animation type.

To fulfill these requirements, you can use this technique

### Step #1

First you need to get the shape of the curve at the starting position:

[image]

### Step #2

Then, by moving the anchor points of the curve in the vector editor, we get the final shape of the curve:

[image]

### Step #3

Next, we write a command to animate the curve:

`<animate attributeName="d" values="path1;path2;path1" />`, where

path1 - Curve shape at the start

path2 - Finish curve shape

as **@Kaiido** said in the comments try not to allow extra spaces before the semicolon

```css
svg {
width:40%;
height:40%;
}
path {
fill:#2F3136;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:4;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="770" height="770" viewBox="0 0 770 770" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >

<path d="M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z" >
<animate attributeName="d"
  dur="4s"
  values="
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 76.8 2.3 110.7-24.2 67.7-52.9 94.4-1.3 137.3-18.5 40.1-16.1 39.1-57.3 105-76.1 93.8-26.8 81.5-74.9 124.6-109.6 22.3-17.9 50.6-23.4 69.2-50.8 41.5-61.1 14.5-80.4 66.9-115.4 0 0 28.1-21.9 36.9-36.9 16.5-28.3 27.7-30.3 26.5-94.6-0.4-21.7 2.5-76.9 19.6-94.6C730.2 67.3 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z"
         repeatcount="indefinite"
         />
         
</path>

</svg>
```

- Option with background image and shadow

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;

}

path {
fill:#2F3136;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0;
fill-opacity:0.5;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px black);
    filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 770 770" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
<image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABxSm.jpg" x="10" width="1125px" height="750px" >
 
</image>
<path   d="M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z" >
<animate id="an_d" attributeName="d"
  dur="6s"
  begin="0s"
  values="
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 76.8 2.3 110.7-24.2 67.7-52.9 94.4-1.3 137.3-18.5 40.1-16.1 39.1-57.3 105-76.1 93.8-26.8 81.5-74.9 124.6-109.6 22.3-17.9 50.6-23.4 69.2-50.8 41.5-61.1 14.5-80.4 66.9-115.4 0 0 28.1-21.9 36.9-36.9 16.5-28.3 27.7-30.3 26.5-94.6-0.4-21.7 2.5-76.9 19.6-94.6C730.2 67.3 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         />
        
</path>

</svg>
</div>
```

- Border animation plus whole block size animation

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;

}

path {
fill:#2F3136;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:0;
fill-opacity:0.5;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 770 770" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
<defs>
<filter id='shadow'>
    <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='2' />
    <feOffset dx='3' dy='3' result='blur' />
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in='blur' />
      <feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic' />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  </defs>
<image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABxSm.jpg" x="10" width="1125px" height="750px" >
 
</image>
<path filter="url(#shadow)"  d="M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z" >
<animate id="an_d" attributeName="d"
  dur="6s"
  begin="0s;an_t.end"
  values="
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 76.8 2.3 110.7-24.2 67.7-52.9 94.4-1.3 137.3-18.5 40.1-16.1 39.1-57.3 105-76.1 93.8-26.8 81.5-74.9 124.6-109.6 22.3-17.9 50.6-23.4 69.2-50.8 41.5-61.1 14.5-80.4 66.9-115.4 0 0 28.1-21.9 36.9-36.9 16.5-28.3 27.7-30.3 26.5-94.6-0.4-21.7 2.5-76.9 19.6-94.6C730.2 67.3 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z;
         M8.1 1.2V721.6c0 0 73.2 20.7 105 16.1 39.9-5.6 63.5-61.7 105-66.9 35-4.4 74.9 1 105-13.8 41.9-20.7 60.2-90.1 92.3-108.4 30.9-17.7 74.9-13.9 101.5-33.5 63.3-46.3 5.3-81.5 76.1-145.3 0 0 47.9-24.3 61.1-46.1 19.6-32.3 18.5-61.6 18.5-111.9 0-21.7 15.2-38.8 32.3-56.5C730.2 121.6 752.7 68.8 719.8 2.9 516.8-0.6 218-0.6 8.1 1.2Z"
         repeatcount="1"
         />
        <animateTransform id="an_t" attributeName="transform" type="scale" dur="12s" begin="an_d.end" values="1;0.5;0.5;1" /> 
</path>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. It's interesting because that's exactly how I intuitively made my initial SVG animation. It's great to know the underlying theory a bit more in depth. Thanks! The issue in my case was in fact the trailing whitespace which was quite ridiculous lol. But it works now. Thank for the additonal styling examples, they will really be helpful in some of my use-cases.